# How to include file and code line number to the log message sent to google cloud logging from google app engine python code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python-logging, google-cloud-logging

In an servece, coded in python 3.10, running on google cloud platform (google appengine), and using google's own client library google-cloud-logging for logging, I want to add the filename and line number to the log message itself.

The library is utiliezed in a standard recommended way:

```
import google.cloud.logging
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.setup_logging(log_level=logging.DEBUG)
... 
logging.info("this is a message")
```

The reason why I want to have the information in the message has to do with how the log is displayed in the google's cloud console Log Explorer.

The cloud logging somehow does get this information (called `sourceLocaltion`) and sends it to the cloud logging API - when I open the log record, I can see the record with all the fields, redacted sample:

```
...
message: "testing hello world info 2023-05-31T17:27:43Z"
timestamp: "2023-05-31T17:27:43Z"
...
severity: "ERROR"
sourceLocation: {
file: "/srv/main.py"
function: "_log2"
line: "55"
...
```

However I could not find a way to show it alongside but after the message. Logs Explorer is customizable. More fields can be added by clicking Edit in the bar of query results. However the fields are added before the message. I really need it after the message. So my choice would be to format the message at the python code level instead.

The normal loggers do it via formatters, easiest included as config.ini files and loaded using logging.config. I would love to be able to do it with google.cloud.logging. I strongly suspect it is possible, but I failed to find how